# Is there any android system API to detect user gestures outside my application?

Tags: android, api

I want to detect a gesture, not in my application but from android system when a user swipe in the home screen of his phone.

For example, when my app is close and in the background, and when the user swipe on his/her phone, my app will detect the gesture in the background.

**I want to know if there's such API. Thanks!**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [AccessbilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService).

Using this, you will be able to get gesture from the user, on different contexts.